# How to make a Python operator as a Slider?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, transforms

I am in the process of finishing an add-on I have been making and I am trying to work on some final tweaks. I am wondering how I can make a Python operator that is a Slider which controls the x, y, or z position of the selected object. Something like the image below except that controls position specifically.

[image]

**Q:** How to make a Python operator as a Slider?

Answer (score 7):

**Set slider property to True**

Consult the docs on **[UILayout.prop](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=uilayout#bpy.types.UILayout.prop)**,

> **prop**`(data, property, text="", text_ctxt="", translate=True,`
> `icon='NONE', expand=False,` **`slider=False`**, `toggle=False,`
> `icon_only=False, event=False, full_event=False, emboss=True, index=-1,`
> `icon_value=0)`

To display the property in the UI  set it to `True`.  The default is `slider = False`

> **slider** (boolean, (optional)) – Use slider widget for numeric values

Sample code

```
def draw(self, context):
    self.layout(context.object, "prop", slider=True)
```

Make sure to set the minimum and maximum of the property, if unset the default values are +/- the maximum possible value on your system and as a result the slider will sit around the middle *and be somewhat meaningless*.

Tip: Edit *`Prefs > Interface > Display`* and enable "Developer Extras" will enable you to right click over any (most) UI element and view source to open the code behind the UI into the text editor.