# Python Control - Float with progressbar

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to figure out how to program such control and a function called eveytime I change the value.

[image]

Thanks guys for any tips or link!

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#update-example

Comment: Thanks batFINGER!

How do we get the progressbar effect on the prop control?

Comment: Can be done easily setting prop  from a modal timer operator. [Example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47398/15543) I have noticed a progress bar class in 2.8  (No idea how to use it, would be handy going forward)

Comment: Actually, I just had to declare slider=True on my layout.prop!

Comment: [Possible Dupe then?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112196/how-to-make-a-python-operator-as-a-slider-scripting-an-addon)