# What UI panel property type is this and how can I create my own (sliders?)

Tags: customization, properties

[image]

Hello, I wanted to add this custom property slider from an object's custom property tab, but so far, I´ve only found out that it will display numbers, but not that "slider" bar, I need.
This is a slide bar taken from a shader. But I´d like to use it in the N panel under a custom property from an object.
How can I call and display such item in a panel?
Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112196/how-to-make-a-python-operator-as-a-slider-scripting-an-addon

Comment: @batFINGER do you think it's possible to call that "true" parameter from the custom property in the UI? (like from the custom property of an object?)

Comment: After running this code, I still get no slider. Could you please test on your side? https://imgur.com/a/gf8uRiz

Comment: Well, no clue on how to do this from a regular custom property. So It will be done using an array of controllers but showing the slider in the N panel via Python. Unless someone could point (to the original question) on how to do it on a custom property....