# How to add a radian property to a panel and have it work?

Tags: scripting, properties, panel

I'm trying to add the Line art crease angle to my viewport panel. I thought it should be fairly straightforward. When I change it to 180 degrees using the slider control I get this in the console area:

```
bpy.context.object.grease_pencil_modifiers["Line Art"].crease_threshold = 3.14159
```

Of course the value is in radians and not degrees, but the slider display is in degrees. All well and good.
But when I place in in a panel thusly:

```
col.prop(bpy.data.objects["Line Art Thin"].grease_pencil_modifiers["Line Art"], "crease_threshold")
```

I get a nice control, which has the degrees shown, and I can manually enter the value by typing in it, but the slider control *does not work.* What is the best way to remedy this situation?

Comment: Probable dupe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112196/how-to-make-a-python-operator-as-a-slider-scripting-an-addon/112209#112209

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to batfinger for pointing me to that link. The answer is straightforward:

```
col.prop(bpy.data.objects["Line Art Thin"].grease_pencil_modifiers["Line Art"], "crease_threshold", slider=True)
```

It needed to have the `slider=True` appended.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that this works because the property is a `'ROTATION'` type.  If the scene unit designated to rotations is degrees (default) it will display as degrees.